# Extend primitives without prototyping them

Tags: javascript

I am working on a pretty ugly library that lets you do some strange things.
Having a graph you can map a set of collections in a chain-like style and when you alter a
value to be altered in the whole system.

The problem came when the end type is a JS primitive.

In my case after making the graph with the values and objects I can do something like this:

```
CHAIN.components[0].value = 20;
```

`components` is a filter function over the graph's nodes using setters and getters.
If there is only one node filtered in components the default value set by the user would be available without doing this:
    CHAIN.components.value = 20;
But rather this:
    CHAIN.components = 20;

Now the problem is that the node could have other methods or properties besides a default ( which in my case is set on `value`.

How can i use the setters and getters on Number object without hacking in the Number.prototype, because `CHAIN.components` is now a Number ( if it's not a primitive i've made it work in an unobtrusive way ), but when i want to call the `CHAIN.components.func()` there is a problem because i would have to append to the Number.prototype the `func` every time i make a set or get on the `components` and then delete it.

Do you have another idea for accomplishing this kind of behavior?

You wanted code so here it is:

```
/*jslint nomen: true, sloppy: true*/
GRID.modules.OHM || Object.extend(GRID.modules, ( function() {
    var Node, Nodes, Ohm, num_proto = Number.prototype.__clone(), str_proto = String.prototype.__clone();
    Node = function(uid) {
        var UID = uid;
        this.getUID = function() {
            return UID;
        };
    };
    Nodes = function() {
        var stack = [];
        this.add = function(id, val) {
            var n = new Node(stack.length);
            val.id = id;
            Object.extend(n, val);
            stack.push(n);
            return n.getUID();
        };
        this.getById = function(id) {
            return stack.filter(function(v) {
                var a = id || v.id;
                return (v.id === a);
            });
        };
        this.getByUID = function(UID) {
            return stack[UID];
        };
        this.get = function(callback) {
            !Object.isString(callback) || ( callback = [callback]);
            var f = Object.isFunction(callback) ? callback : (Object.isArray(callback) ? function(k) {
                return (callback.indexOf(k.id) >= 0);
            } : function(k) {
                return true;
            });
            return stack.filter(f);
        };
    };
    Ohm = function(n) {
        var graph = n || (new Nodes()), filters = {}, __nodes = {}, addGS = function(obj, name, conf, binder) {
            var alfa = {};
            Object.extend(alfa, conf);
            if (!alfa.get) {
                alfa.get = function() {
                    var a = this.g.getById(this.p);
                    return a.length === 1 ? a[0] : a;
                }.bind(binder);
            } else {
                alfa.get = alfa.get.bind(binder);
            }
            if (!alfa.set) {
                alfa.set = function(value) {
                    this.g.getById(this.p).forEach(function(k) {
                        Object.extend(k, value);
                        return true;
                    });
                }.bind(binder);
            } else {
                alfa.set = alfa.set.bind(binder);
            }
            Object.defineProperty(obj, name, alfa);
        }, add = function(id, node) {
            if (__nodes.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
                addGS(__nodes, id, {
                    enumerable : true
                }, {
                    t : this,
                    p : id,
                    g : graph
                });
            }
            return graph.add(id, node || {});
        };
        Object.extend(this, {
            add : function() {
                add.apply(this, arguments);
            },
            map : function(name, f, that) {
                var n = name, filterer = ['add', 'map', '__all'];
                n = Object.isFunction(n) ? name.apply(that, arguments.slice(3)) : n;
                if (filterer.indexOf(n.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                    console.log("You can't map over a basic property of object !!! Please read the freakin' manual.");
                    return null;
                }
                if (!filters.hasOwnProperty(n)) {
                    filters[n] = new Ohm(graph);
                    addGS(this, n, {
                        get : function() {
                            this.g.get(this.f).forEach(function(v, key, arr) {
                                var temp, binder;
                                if (arr.length !== 1) {
                                    if (!this.filt.hasOwnProperty(v.id)) {
                                        addGS(this.filt, v.id, {
                                            set : function(value) {
                                                this.t.g.getById(this.p).filter(this.t.f).forEach(function(k) {
                                                    Object.extend(k, value);
                                                });
                                            },
                                            get : function() {
                                                var a = this.t.g.getById(this.p).filter(this.t.f);
                                                return a.length === 1 ? a[0] : a;
                                            }
                                        }, {
                                            t : this,
                                            p : v.id
                                        });
                                        (key !== arr.length - 1) || Object.extend(this.filt, this.g.get(this.f));
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    if (Object.isFunction(v.__new__)) {
                                        v.__default = function() {
                                            return Object.extend((new this.__new__(arguments)), this);
                                        };
                                    }
                                    if (!Object.isUndefined(v.__default)) {
                                        temp = this.filt;
                                        this.filt = Object.isFunction(v.__default) ? v.__default.bind(v) : v.__default;
                                        if (Object.isNumber(this.filt) || Object.isString(this.filt)) {
                                            var prot = Object.isNumber(this.filt) ? Number : String;
                                            for (var i in temp) {
                                                if (temp.hasOwnProperty(i) && !prot.prototype.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                                                    var bin = {
                                                        t : temp,
                                                        m : i,
                                                        p : prot,

                                                    };
                                                    Object.defineProperty(prot.prototype, i, {
                                                        set : function(value) {
                                                            Object.defineProperty(this.p.prototype, this.m, {
                                                                configurable : true, // defaults to false
                                                                writable : false,
                                                                value : 1
                                                            });
                                                            delete this.p.prototype[this.m];
                                                            this.t[this.m] = value;
                                                        }.bind(bin),
                                                        get : function() {
                                                            Object.defineProperty(this.p.prototype, this.m, {
                                                                configurable : true, // defaults to false
                                                                writable : false,
                                                                value : 1
                                                            });
                                                            delete this.p.prototype[this.m];
                                                            return this.t[this.m];
                                                        }.bind(bin),
                                                        enumerable : true,
                                                        configurable : true
                                                    });
                                                }
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            Object.extend(this.filt, temp);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (Object.isNumber(this.filt) || Object.isString(this.filt)) {
                                        var prot = Object.isNumber(this.filt) ? Number : String;
                                        for (var i in v) {
                                            if (v.hasOwnProperty(i) && !prot.prototype.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                                                var bin = {
                                                    t : v,
                                                    m : i,
                                                    p : prot,

                                                };
                                                Object.defineProperty(prot.prototype, i, {
                                                    set : function(value) {
                                                        Object.defineProperty(this.p.prototype, this.m, {
                                                            configurable : true, // defaults to false
                                                            writable : false,
                                                            value : 1
                                                        });
                                                        delete this.p.prototype[this.m];
                                                        this.t[this.m] = value;
                                                    }.bind(bin),
                                                    get : function() {
                                                        Object.defineProperty(this.p.prototype, this.m, {
                                                            configurable : true, // defaults to false
                                                            writable : false,
                                                            value : 1
                                                        });
                                                        delete this.p.prototype[this.m];
                                                        return this.t[this.m];
                                                    }.bind(bin),
                                                    enumerable : true,
                                                    configurable : true
                                                });
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        Object.extend(this.filt, v);
                                    }
                                }
                            }, this);
                            return this.filt;
                        },
                        set : function(value) {
                            this.g.get(this.f).forEach(function(k) {
                                Object.extend(k, value);
                            });
                        }
                    }, {
                        t : this,
                        f : f,
                        g : graph,
                        filt : filters[n]
                    });
                }
            }
        }, true, true);
        addGS(this, '__all', {
            get : function() {
                var a = this.g.getById();
                Object.extend(__nodes, a.length === 1 ? a[0] : a);
                return __nodes;
            },
            enumerable : true
        }, {
            t : this,
            p : null,
            g : graph
        });
    };
    window['Ω'] = Ohm;
    return {
        OHM : Ohm,
    };
}()));
```

And now the demo:

```
var c = new Ω();
c.add('ann', {
__default : 58,
blah : 98,
ceva : function()
{
    console.log('asd');
}
});
c.add('ann2',{
    __default: function(){
       console.log('hello');
    },
    abc: 78,
    dce: function(){
       console.log(' world');
    }
};
c.add('b2', {
__new__ : function() {
    this.init = function() {
        this.id = 86;
    };
    this.mer = function() {
        console.log(this);
    };
},
els : 'asadar'
});
c.map('b2', function(k) {
return k.id === 'b2';
});
c.map('ann', function(k) {
return k.id === 'ann';
});
c.map('ann2', function(k) {
return k.id === 'ann2';
});
console.log(c.ann); // returns 58 ( the __default value )
console.log(c.ann.blah); // returns 98
console.log(c.ann.blah.blah); // undefined
console.log(c.ann2);  // function()
c.ann2(); // prints out 'hello'
c.ann2.cde(); // prints out 'world'
c.ann2 = 60;
console.log(c.ann2); // 60
console.log(c.ann2.cde()); // prints out 'world'
```

This code works, but the part where i have to use the Number or String prototype bothers me. Do you have another way of doing this?

The reason is to do something that someone said it could be done in PHP but not JS, this guy had recently been working with me on WebGL shaders and hated that he had to write 700 lines of code to use multiple effect combined with FBO instead of 100 which would took him with a similar tool like this one which was written in PHP. So yes i KNOW the accessors on primitive prototypes is a hack but how can i make it different without having to use valueOf if the chain end object is a primitive?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code for your accessors, but shouldn't the `get` method return an object reference (like `this`) instead of their `value` property?

Comment: @bfavaretto I've added some code ( have fun ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, now I've read the attached code (but could not follow all of it). Lacks some comments, but I won't bitch about that, my own codes are not better as I don't expect anybody to read or understand them :-)

You are right, the part where you extend the native prototypes is scary. From what I understand, you define an accessor property on the Number or String prototype before returning a number / string. Both on getting and setting, the accessor property is overwritten by a data property (???), then the whole property is deleted, before you store / return the value. This seems to be a clever hack to allow custom properties on primitive values, yet:

- There is a high risk of collisions. It might be possible to lower that by using the `this` value as a key in a lookup table (to differentiate `(5).x` from `(3).x`), but it still can't be fully avoided.
- Properties that remove themselves on accessing / setting are extremely unintuitive. Avoid that.
- arbitrarily changing accessor properties on the prototype of primitives are costly. That's 4 performance-contras combined. No engine will be able to optimize this. And you seem to use them quite often.

If you really needed this (I still didn't get your reason), I'd use a variant with a lookup-table. It should reduce collisions (not sure how your code handled them), does not change the accessor properties ones they're defined and is therefore more persistent (though it might leak then):

```
// Let's call this
// PRIMITIVE PROXIES
// as they proxy real objects behind primitive values
var proxy = _.map( { // some map that works on Objects
    string: String.prototype,
    number: Number.prototype
}, function closure(type, proto) {
    var table = {};
    function setupProperty(prop) {
        if (prop in proto) return; // ah, we already proxied this kind of object
        Object.defineProperty(proto, prop, {
            configurable:true, // for deleting
            get: function getter() {
                // "this" is the primitive value
                if (!this in table)
                    return undefined;
                return table[this][prop]; // get prop from obj
            },
            set: function setter(val) {
                if (this in table)
                    table[this][prop] = val; // pass val to obj
            }
        });
    }
    return {
        create: function createProxy(prim, obj) {
            if (prim in table) // we already did create a proxy on this primitive
                return; // let's abort. You might continue to overwrite
            table[prim] = obj;
            Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(setupProperty);
            return prim; // the new "proxy"
        },
        move: function moveName(from, to) {
            if (to in table) return false;
            table[to] = table[from];
            delete table[from];
            return true;
        }
    };
});
proxy.create = function(prim, obj) {
    return proxy[typeof prim].create(prim, obj);
};
proxy.move = function(from, to) {
    return proxy[typeof from].create(from, to);
};
// USAGE:
// proxy.create works just like Object.extend
> var c = {ann: 58},
>     o = {blah: 98};
> proxy.create(c.ann, o);
> 58..blah
98
> c.ann.blah
98
> (58).blah = 60;
> o
{blah: 60}
> var num = c.ann; // 58
> c.ann.blah = function(){return "Hello"};
> num.blah()
"Hello"
> proxy.move(c.ann, c.ann = 78);
> c.ann
78
> (58).blah
undefined
> c.ann.blah()
"Hello"
> // getters/setters for properties are global:
> c.ann.blub = "something"; // does not work, there is no getter
> c.ann.blub
undefined
> proxy.create(58, {blub: "foo"})
> c.ann.blub // still returns
undefined
> c.ann.blub = "bar"; // but can be set now
> (58).blub + (78).blub
"foobar"
> // infinite lookup loops are possible:
> proxy.create("loop", {x:"loop"});
> "loop" === "loop".x
true
> "loop".x.x.x.….x
"loop"
```

However, there is one thing you will never be able to work around:

> Unlike objects, primitive values are not unique; they have no identity.

You will never be able to distinguish `c.ann` from `58`, or `"loop"` from `"loop".x`, and so both will have a property or not. This is not a good premise to build an API upon.

So, I still recommend to use `Number` and `String` objects. You don't need to subclass them (as shown in my previous answer), as you don't seem to have (m)any methods on them, so you can easily build them:

```
c.ann = new Number(58);
c.ann.blah = 98;
return c;
```

There should be hardly a difference, expect for the `typeof` operator. Could you maybe add some more examples that use the `__default` value?

> but how can I make it different without having to use valueOf if the chain end object is a primitive?

To answer this simple question: That guy was right, it cannot be done in JavaScript without hacking native prototypes. And you are right, the hack is quite ugly :-)

Comment: I've tried the `new Number` but at get i will still have the object in which the value it's wrapped instead of the value. And there won't even be (98).blah because any other number won't be prototype ( or it will be but it will get deleted after i finish the get part ), so c.ann will be 58  and will also have the blah method but any other number won't have this method becase i erase it, i had some problems and this is why i am asking you. Initially c.ann.blah.blah would have existed if i wouldn't have deleted at any set or get on the primitives prototypes. Could you elaborate lookup-table?

Comment: And as a reply to `arbitrarily changing accessor properties on the prototype of primitives are costly` i have to say that i know that and this is actually my question. Is there another way to do the same thing? P.S.  I have added more examples. And please do not ask me about the `__new__` thing because it's like making a class out of an object ( aka putting the egg back in the chicken ).

Comment: Yes, I understood that it would be deleted on the first accessing - only that means that not only `ann.blah.blah` won't work, but also successive `ann.blah, ann.blah`. Yet could you please elaborate where in your code an object wrapper causes issues? It should not, that was my point.

Comment: No actually c.ann.blah repeatedly is working. well let me put it this way if i would have set ann to be a `new Number(58)` i could've extended it with no problem, but when i would've made my call `c.ann` it would return an Object and not 58 and to get it to return 58 i would have to call `valueOf`. The part that is bothering me is in the map function in the ugly part where instead of making an extend i have to hack the prototype. I hope i am not too stubborn but i hope i understand what i want to accomplish. This is all for my dream to come true ( become a JS GURU and surpass Crockford ).

Comment: Stand back, I'm first :-) No honestly, I think I understand your problem. It seems there is no other solution that this ugly thing, but I still don't get why you need the chain end value to be primitive (as an object would be suited better). What do you approach? Is it just a nice-to-have, or are there any technical limitations that enforce this?

Comment: The guy (codename Khael) around here ( please address all your swearing to him ) thought it as a nice-to-have and actually i think that way too because this would be a module for professionals only who will know what the end-value will be. On the other hand trying to see what other people would think about solving this kind of problem and use this kind of thing is the second reason i posted this here.

Comment: Yes, it would be a really cool feature - but I fear it is not possible. This hack of the native prototypes was a clever idea, but it's bad practise. I'd say the solution to this kind of problem are the native object wrappers - that's what they were designed for. The usecase of distinct primitives with unique properties is contrary to the definition of "primitive value". If the library targets professionals, they will know what object wrappers are, why you used them and how to deal with them. Real professionals would beat you if you'd use the prototype hack :-)

Comment: Yes i know that and i too wanted to beat khael when i've heard what he wanted, i think i will make a switch in the module called `isKhael` which if true will make accessors on primitive's prototype else it will use the native wrappers. SO is sending me on discussion chat so i have to say thank you for the support and hope you do not mind if i make this question a bounty to see other ideas, if any.

Comment: You need not to follow the chat invitation. I have extended my answer now with a (untested) concept of "Primitive Proxies", a better implementation of your hack :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20294/discussion-between-helly0d-and-bergi)

Answer (score 1):

Don't make it a primitive number, make it an object that behaves like a number. You could use a `Number` object and extend that with your custom properties (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9338486/1048572), but why not subclass `Number` in general? It only needs to preserve a [`valueOf` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) that returns the number:

```
function MyNumber(n) {
    this.value = Number(n);
}
MyNumber.prototype = Object.create(Number.prototype, {constructor:{value:MyNumber}});
MyNumber.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    return this.value;
};
// OK, we have to overwrite those methods as they don't work on subclasses of Number
["toExponential", "toFixed", "toLocaleString", "toPrecision", "toString"].forEach(function(name) {
    MyNumber.prototype[name] = function() {
        return Number.prototype[name].apply(new Number(this.value), arguments);
    };
});

// now extend the prototype with other properties, e.g. chaining methods
```

Of course, you might need to make `components` a setter that transforms a given number (or Number) into a MyNumber:

```
var actualNumber = new MyNumber;
Object.defineProperty(MyFabulousChainingThing, "components", {
    get: function() { return actualNumber; },
    set: function(x) { actualNumber.value = Number(x); }
});
```

Comment: The problem is that i also want to use the object without calling valueOf. I tried this way myself. so if i do a `console.log(g);` where `g= new MyNumber(10);` it should return 10, but if i do `g.myFunction()` to work also without having to prototype Number ( which in my case does the trick but in a very ugly way ). Any ideas?

Comment: The nice thing about `valueOf` is that you don't *need* to call it - it will [also] be used for the implicit type conversion: `new MyNumber(9) + 1 === 10`

Comment: The problem is that if `component` is an instanceOf `MyNumber` and the chain stops there it should return the value, but if you continue the chain it should enter inside the Node object and be called form there forth.

Comment: @helly0d: That's impossible, the `component` is no quantum mechanics particle which decides about its state only when inspecting. However, you can use instances of `MyNumber` wherever you could use primitive numbers or Number objects, too.

Comment: Please see the code i've just added. JOKE: I think i just made it to be quantuum mechanics.