# In JavaScript, is there a way to inherit from the Number function?

Tags: javascript

So I know I can do this...

```
Number.prototype.square = function () { return this * this }
 [Function]
4..square()
 16
```

Is there a way to inherit from the Number function so that I don't have to modify the Number prototype?  With a function or object, I can inherit like this...

```
var NewObject = new Object()
var NewFunction = new Function()
```

Is there a was to do something similar w/ Number?

Comment: The question is not clear :-/

Comment: I edited the question for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can easily inherit from the `Number.prototype`. The trick is to make your objects convertible to numbers by giving them a `.valueOf` method:

```
function NumLib(n) {
    if (!(this instanceof NumLib)) return new NumLib(n);
    this.valueOf = function() {
        return n;
    }
}
NumLib.prototype = Object.create(Number.prototype);
NumLib.prototype.square = function () { return this * this }
```

The cast will happen whenever a mathematical operation is applied to the object, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13606589/1048572). The native `Number` methods don't really like to be called on derived objects, though.

Answer (score 1):

using `Object.defineProperty` allows you to have a little more control over the object.

```
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype,'square',{value:function(){
 return this*this
},writable:false,enumerable:false});
//(5).square();
```

with your own lib it's the same...

```
Object.defineProperty(NumLib.prototype,'square',{value:function(){
 return this.whatever*this.whatever
},writable:false,enumerable:false});
```