# Javascript Object with default value

Tags: javascript

What I want to achieve seems quite simple but I'm not sure if it's possible.

I'd like to have an object that returns a certain value if no property is specified. For example:

```
console.log(obj) // Returns "123"
console.log(obj.x) // Returns "ABC"
```

Comment: No, that's not possible. What would you need this for?

Comment: you can't do it for `console.log(obj)`, but you can do it for `console.log(obj + '')`

Comment: Have a look [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13606589/1048572) though

Comment: @Bergi Misuse of that code will end in tears. I stand by your first answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `toString()` method in the prototype for your custom object.

```
function MyObj() {
}
MyObj.prototype.toString = function () {
    return '123';
};
var obj = new MyObj();
obj.x = 'ABC';
console.log(obj + '');
console.log(obj.x + '');
```

Comment: As @zb points out this only works by coercing the object into a string with `+ ''` in the log call.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it can be done using [Symbol's toPrimitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive):

```
const primaryColor = {
  default: 'green',
  darker: 'silver',
  lighter: 'white',
}

Object.defineProperty(primaryColor, Symbol.toPrimitive, {
  value: () => primaryColor.default
});
```

so, we got something like:

```
console.log('primary color: ' + primaryColor.darker) // returns "primary color: silver"
console.log('primary color: ' + primaryColor) // returns "primary color: green"
```