# Is it possible to implement a member that returns both a function and a number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, proxy, prototype, getter-setter

I'm trying to simulate the following:

```
foo.bar // --> 3
foo.bar.baz() // --> 7
```

I tried using Proxy, getters, prototypes...

Can this even be done? If so, how?

Comment: Nothing can be both a number and a function.

Comment: However, you actually seem to be looking for [a number with a custom method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13606375/1048572), which is possible but not advisable.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't what you're looking for, but one (silly) option would be to mutate `Number.prototype`:

```js
const foo = {
  bar: 3
};
Number.prototype.baz = () => 7;
console.log(foo.bar);
console.log(foo.bar.baz());
```

Aside from that hack, I'm pretty sure what you're looking for isn't possible, because otherwise `foo.baz` would have to be evaluated to an *object*, not a number, in the second line, contradicting the condition of the first line.

Answer (score 0):

You can (to some degree) do this with `valueOf`. However, you need coercion to trigger `valueOf`

```
let foo = {
   bar: {
      valueOf: () => 3,
      baz: () => "baz"
   }
}
foo.bar.baz() //"baz";
+foo.bar //3
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance "However, you need coercion to trigger valueOf"