# Can I assign Proxy to Number.prototype somehow?

Tags: javascript, methods, proxy, numbers, prototype

Can I assign Proxy to Number.prototype somehow?
I want to be able to call:

`42..anyMethod`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found the solution.

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(Number.prototype, new Proxy({}, {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    return prop in target || typeof prop === 'symbol' ? target[prop] : { target, prop, receiver };
  }
}));
```

Comment: Oh, ingenious! I forgot that not all builtin prototypes are immutable-prototype exotic objects. So yes, while you cannot replace `Number.prototype` with a proxy, you can still inject it in the number inheritance hierarchy. I would recommend to use `new Proxy(Object.prototype, …)` though.

Answer (score -1):

No, this is not possible. The builtin prototypes are locked down, `Number.prototype` is not writable and even if it was then `Number` would still ignore it and construct objects with the builtin prototype.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13606375/1048572) though that does fancy weird things to `Number.prototype`.

Comment: @gkucmierz Taking the question title "*assign Proxy to `Number.prototype`*" literally, the answer is still correct