# Create a construct that evaluates to a string and can have other strings as properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, properties, es6-proxy

I'd like to make particular JavaScript construct, with appropriate TypeScript typings

I want my construct to:

1. return a string when evaluated
2. have properties that return different strings when evaluated

in a similar fashion to how you can make nested callable functions:

```
const fn = () => "foo"
fn.bar = () => "bar"

fn() // "foo"
fn.bar() // "bar"
```

something like

```
const foo = "foo";
foo.bar = "bar" // Unfortunately doesn't work

foo // "foo"
foo.bar // "bar" 

type Foo = "foo" & { bar: "bar" }
```

It could also be a property tied to a parent `Proxy` object, if necessary. When I tried implementing it with a Proxy, I ran into the problem of not being able to differentiate shallow (`proxy.foo`) and deep (`proxy.foo.bar`) property access from the get trap:

```
const proxy = new Proxy({}, { 
  get: (target, prop) => {
    // prop is "foo" for both `proxy.foo` and `proxy.foo.bar` accesses, 
    // presumably because they are two separate property access operations 
    // `proxy.foo.bar` = `(proxy.foo).bar`
  }
}
```

is it even possible to make such construct in JavaScript?
And is possible to type it in TS?

---

**Edit: Describing my use case**

I want this to create a schema that maps semantic sections of my website to their respective urls:

```
const urlSchema = someMagic();

urlSchema.settings // `/settings`
urlSchema.settings.personal // `/settings/personal`
```

I then want to import this schema from throughout the app to create links etc.

Comment: What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) that you want to use this construct for?

Comment: @Bergi : Hey, I added edited my post to include the use case. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Not possible. But you can easily make `urlSchema.settings` return an object that evaluates to the string `/settings` when used in `String(urlSchema.settings)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want my construct to return a string when evaluated and have properties

That is not possible. An expression that evaluates to a string returns a string value, and a string is a primitive value not an object that could have properties. A proxy won't help here since a proxy is always an object as well.

See also [Extend primitives without prototyping them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13606375/1048572).