# Can javascript build an object when access it directly return string or number, access it's property return it's property

Tags: javascript, typescript

like this:

```
const o = {
  value: 'value',
  label: 'label'
}

o === 'value' // true, direct access it return 'value'
o.label === 'label' // true
o.value === 'value' // true
```

rewriting `o.toString` does not satisfy me because i want it to work not only in `console.log` but anywhere.

Comment: You can't change what the direct access does, you can make the last two examples work for any property access by using a proxy.

Comment: `o === "value"` will never be `true` if `o` is an object.  The [`===` strict equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) isn't something you can override.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13606375/1048572

Comment: seems there is no way for sample 1 `o === 'value'`

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible for `o === 'value'` to be `true` with strict equality since `o` is an object, not a string.

However, you can make it true with `==` as loose equality will attempt to coerce both operands to the same type before comparison. You cannot change the behavior of just accessing the object itself, though.

```js
const o = {
  value: 'value',
  label: 'label',
  valueOf() {
    return this.value;
  }
}

console.log('' + o);
console.log(o == 'value');
console.log(o.label === 'label');
console.log(o.value === 'value');
```

Comment: There's also `toString()` for when you need to override the default `[Object object]` when interpolating the object into a string.